# How to speed up this for-loop code (for large matrix `H_sparse`)?

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix-multiplication, large-data

`H_sparse` is a large matrix with size 20,000-by-5,000. The matrix-vector product `dk = A * Del_H;` in the code below is time consuming. How can I speed up this code?

This code is another way to get an equivalent result to the built-in function `pinv(H_Sparse)` in MATLAB. I think MATLAB uses mex files and `bsxfun` in `pinv`, so it's fast.

But *in theory* the below algorithm is faster:

```
function PINV_H_Spp = Recur_Pinv_Comp( H_Sparse ) 
         L           = 1;
         H_candidate = H_Sparse(:,L); 
         A           = pinv( H_candidate );
         for L = 1:size( H_Sparse, 2 ) - 1
             L = L + 1; 
             Del_H = H_Sparse(:,L);
             dk    = A * Del_H;
             Ck    =     Del_H - H_candidate * dk; 
             Gk    = pinv( Ck ); 
             A     = A - dk * Gk; 
             A(end+1,:) = Gk; 
             H_candidate(:,end+1) = Del_H;
         end
         PINV_H_Spp = A;
```

The code can be compared with `pinv(H_Sparse)`, using `H_Sparse = rand(20000, 5000)` as sample data.

Answer (score 1):

A few points of improvement:

- You can change your loop index to `2:size(H_Sparse, 2)` and remove the line `L = L + 1;`.
- There's no need to create a separate variable `H_candidate`, since it's only partitions of `H_Sparse`. Instead, just [index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) `H_sparse` accordingly and you'll save on memory.
- Instead of building your matrix `A` row-by-row, you can [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) it and update it using [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). This usually provides some speed-up.
- Return `A` as your output. No need to put it in another variable.

Here's a new version of the code incorporating the above improvements:

```
function A = Recur_Pinv_Comp(H_Sparse)
  [nRows, nCols] = size(H_Sparse);
  A = [pinv(H_Sparse(:, 1)); zeros(nRows-1, nCols)];
  for L = 2:nCols
    Del_H = H_Sparse(:, L);
    dk = A(1:L-1, :)*Del_H;
    Ck = Del_H - H_Sparse(:, 1:L-1)*dk;
    Gk = pinv(Ck);
    A(1:L-1, :) = A(1:L-1, :) - dk*Gk;
    A(L, :) = Gk;
  end
end
```

In addition, it looks like your calls to [`pinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) only ever operate on column vectors, so you may be able to replace them with a simple [array transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) and scaling by the sum of the squares of the vector (which might speed things up a little more):

```
Gk  = Ck.'./(Ck.'*Ck);
```